# Flutter - Show Dialog NumberPicker on Tap TextFormField

Tags: forms, flutter, dialog

The problem is simple: I need to show [numberpickerdialog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/numberpicker) when i click in form field. Then i need to asign numberpicker value to field.

FORM FIELD

```
 final maxValue = new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("entra");
           _showDialog(context);
              },
              child: TextFormField(
                  //controller: inputMaxValue,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: DemoLocalizations.of(context).trans('value-meter-max'),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[300], width: 2.5),
                    ),
                  )),
            );
```

DIALOG

```
  void _showDialog(context) {
    showDialog<double>(
    context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new NumberPickerDialog.decimal(
          minValue: 1,
          maxValue: 10,
          title: new Text("Pick a new price"),
          initialDoubleValue: _currentPrice,
        );
      }
    ).then((double value) {
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() => _currentPrice = value);
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem: When i click field dialog doesn´t show: How can i launch showDialog when i click in this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recreated your case and noticed that the issue could be due to `TextFormField` used. Ideally, a `TextFormField` should only be used to edit a text because we are clicking on it anyway which enables the field with cursor. If we are wrapping it with `GestureDetector`, we are trying to tap on it again which could be conflicting with the click event.
I would rather use `InputDecorator` and wrap it with `GestureDetector`. Here's a working example of it which opens a dialog:

```
  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
           child: GestureDetector(
               child: InputDecorator(
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                     labelText: 'Test'
                 ),
               ),
             onTap: () {
                 _showDialog();
             },
           )
      )
      );

  }

  void _showDialog() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );   }
```

[image]